# Is it possible to scroll ScrollPane programmatically to given position?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

Is it possible to scroll [`ScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) programmatically to given position?

`ScrollPane#vvalue` and `ScrollPane#hvalue` are useless, because they vary from 0 to 1. Are there any absolute properties or I should code them myself?

Answer (score 4):

Those properties are not useless, you just need to know how to use them correctly. (There are no methods allowing you to specify absolute values directly.)

Assuming the `ScrollBar` is visible, you know the following equation

```
topLeft / (contentSize - viewportSize) = scrollValue / scrollMax
```

This can be reformulated as

```
scrollValue = (topLeft * scrollMax) / (contentSize - viewportSize)
            = topLeft / (contentSize - viewportSize)

hvalue = topLeftX / (contentWidth - viewportWidth)
vvalue = topLeftY / (contentHeight - viewportHeight)
```

Where `topLeftX` and `topLeftY` are the x and y coordiantes of the pixel in the top left corner of the viewport. Use the [`viewportBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#viewportBoundsProperty) to determine the size of the viewport.

Comment: You could also (I believe) set (or bind) the scrollpane's `hmax` to `contentWidth-viewportWidth` (and similarly for `vmax`) if you wanted the value to be in pixel coordinates.

Comment: This is hard to follow.. can someone produce a static function that takes the ScrollPane and the Node that actually scrolls to it?

Comment: for a vertical scrollbar: scrolledPixelsY = (contentHeight - ViewPortHeight)*vValue. Similar calculation for horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean move the scroll pane a given number of pixels then get the image size and calculate how much you need to move with `hvalue` or `vvalue`.

`int pixelsH = 45;
int change = pixelsH/scrollpane.getWidth();
scrollpane.setHvalue(scrollpane.getHValue() + change);`

Same concept for vertical change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setHvalue` and `setVvalue` to position your scrollPane.

Values can be calculated with respect to `Nodes`

For eg:

`double nodeX = dummyNode.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX();
 double nodeY = dummyNode.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();
 double scrollPaneWidth = dummyScrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()
 double scrollPaneHeight = dummyScrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()
 dummyScrollPane.setVvalue(nodeY/height);
 dummyScrollPane.setHvalue(nodeX/width);`

Comment: I doubt that this would produce correct results, since you do not take the visible area into account. Furthermore it seems like you decided to change some of the variable names somewhere in the code.

Comment: Yes @fabian, I missed on the correct variable names in the snippet, thanks for pointing that. Besides this answers the question of scrolling programmatically to a calculated position.

Comment: this doesn't work when the dummynode is far out from the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

@trilogy asked for a code answer to this question... And here it is:

```java
static void scrollToPosition(ScrollPane scrollPane, double topLeftX, double topLeftY) {
    Bounds contentBounds = scrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal();
    Bounds viewportBounds = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
        
    double hValue = topLeftX / (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewportBounds.getWidth());
    double vValue = topLeftY / (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewportBounds.getHeight());

    scrollPane.setHvalue(hValue);
    scrollPane.setVvalue(vValue);
}
```